# Inconsistent results of POS tagging between core nlp demo and parser demo

Tags: stanford-nlp

Inconsistent results of POS tagging between

P: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/

and

C: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

E.g.,

C: We went east/JJ to Oslo.
P: We went east/RB to Oslo.

C: We are all/DT getting older.
P: We are all/RB getting older.

C: Are you getting excited/VBN about your vacation?
P: Are you getting excited/JJ about your vacation?

C: Did you do/VBP that?
P: Did you do/VB that?

It seems that the parser performs better than core nlp, but I cannot replicate the parser results by switching between the model provided in the core nlp zip file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will get different part of speech tag results if you use these different pipelines:

`tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse`

vs.

`tokenize,ssplit,parse`

The latter will perform part of speech tagging as part of the parsing process.  The former uses the MEMM sequence tagging model that is dedicated to part of speech tagging.