# StanfordCoreNLP: Different parses for same sentece when using local CoreNLP server and Web interface

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford's CoreNLP excellent architecture and it basically works very well. However, occassionally I stumble upon seemingly simple sentences where the parses are arguably off. For example for the sentence:

- I've heard that John never trains

I get the following parse tree:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP I))
      (VP (VBP 've)
      (VP (VBN heard)
        (SBAR (IN that)
          (NP
            (NP (NNP John))
            (NP
              (ADVP (RB never))
              (NP (NNS trains)))))))
    (. .)))
```

where the parser interprets "trains" as noun. But when I enter this sentence in the official [demo interface](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp), the result is:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP I))
    (VP (VBP 've)
      (VP (VBN heard)
        (SBAR (IN that)
          (S
            (NP (NNP John))
            (ADVP (RB never))
            (VP (VBZ trains))))))
    (. .)))
```

which looks much more meaningful. At the bottom of the page it says `Parser englishPCFG.ser.gz`. I'm using the same model but also tried `englishSR.ser.gz` with no change.

I'm running the [CoreNLP as a server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html), starting it with:

```
java -mx8g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 60000
```

In my Java code I create a client as follow:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,ner,depparse");
StanfordCoreNLPClient pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLPClient(props, "http://localhost", 9000, 2);
```

What I need to change in my setup to get the same result as in the demo interface?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939806/inconsistent-results-of-pos-tagging-between-core-nlp-demo-and-parser-demo

Comment: I actually found this in the CoreNLP F.A.Q, but it didn't work for me. Even when I remove `pos`, I can see in the server output `Adding annotator pos` and that it is using the `left3words` tagger. Maybe there is some caching going on? But I do restart the server each time, just to be sure. The only thing that seems to have an effect is to manually change the POS tagger model with `props.setProperty("pos.model", "english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");`